# XAMPP - Windows - Access to the requested object is only available from the local network

Tags: xampp

When going to localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/ I get the following error:

```
New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested directory is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".
```

It was working yesterday and I haven't made any changes.

I tried looking for an answer and modified my httpd-xampp.conf file to say "Require all granted"

```
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "/xampp/php/"
<Directory "/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all denied
    <Files "php-cgi.exe">
          Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory "/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "/xampp/htdocs/xampp">   
    <IfModule php7_module>
        <Files "status.php">
            php_admin_flag safe_mode off
        </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
            <Files "webalizer.php">
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
            </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I've looked for other possible solutions but I can't find any. Has anyone had the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and changed the phpmyadmin section in the 'httpd-xampp.conf' file like this and it worked perfectly:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```